# Error using `npm install font-awesome`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, font-awesome, fontawesome-4.4.0

I tried installing Font Awesome using

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

However `npm` is throwing errors

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\a\Desktop\Code\faTest\node_modules\font-awesome
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\a\Desktop\Code\faTest\node_modules\font-awesome' -> 'C:\Users\a\Desktop\Code\faTest\node_modules\.font-awesome.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-25T16_52_23_476Z-debug.log
```

Tried running the following

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm
npm install
npm install --save font-awesome
```

but I still end up with the same error.

Running Windows 10, npm 5.5.1, node 7.9.0

Anyone getting the same issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see whether some other application has instances of node running in the background. If so, try to terminate them and then retry your npm command.

Or run node.js as administrator.

Comment: Node was running in another virutal desktop. Stopping node solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to [Yarn package manager](https://yarnpkg.com/) (doing so took me less than an hour on my large project). Built by Facebook and Google to [fix the issues](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360) everyone has had with npm for a long time.